# Combinatorics and symmetries of Kronecker Powers

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the $k$-th Kronecker power $A^{\otimes k}\in\mathbb{R}^{n^k\times n^k}$ of some square matrix $A\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$. Here we define the Kronecker power inductively as
$$ 
A^{\otimes k} = A^{\otimes (k-1)}\otimes A 
$$
with $A^{\otimes 1} = A$ and $\otimes$ being the symbol for the Kronecker product.

Assuming all the elements in $A\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ are distinct, its $k$-th power has
$$
{n^2+k-1}\choose{n^2-1}
$$
distinct elements, corresponding to the different monomials of total degree $k$ of the $n^2$ entries of $A$. This, out of the $(n^k)^2$ elements.

Take for example the matrix
$$ 
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}& a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21}& a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31}& a_{32} & a_{33} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

for $A^{\otimes 2}$ we could construct a map ${\rm value}\to{\rm indexList}$ for example:  $a_{11}^3\to\{(1,1)\}$, $(a_{11}a_{13})\to\{(1,2),(1,4)\}$, $a_{12}^3\to\{(1,5)\}$, $(a_{11}a_{1,3})\to\{(1,3),(1,7)\}$... and so forth and so on, for all monomials $$a_{11}^{i_{1}}a_{12}^{i_{2}}a_{13}^{i_{3}}a_{21}^{i_{4}}a_{22}^{i_{5}}a_{23}^{i_{6}}a_{31}^{i_{7}}a_{32}^{i_{8}}a_{33}^{i_{9}}$$
with powers $i_{j}\in\{0,1,2\}$ for $j\in\{1,\ldots,9\}$. We have only 45 monomials (or unique values in the matrix) out of 81 elements.

I was wondering if there is an efficient way of computing/storing the results of the Kronecker powers by exploiting these symmetries.

Comment: Each element of the result has a "unique" form given by ordering  both the pairs and the elements of a pair given in ascending order. You'd need some form of encoding for the indices that relies on recurrence (not unlike pascal's triangle) to encode the indices without redundancy.